# Building xcarchive and ipa in the same job in Jenkins

Tags: ios7, jenkins, ipa, xcarchive

I am working on Jenkins CI on iMAC.
I have successfully generated .xcarchive and .ipa files in separate jobs in Jenkins.
what i want to know is can we generate both the files within the same job.?
is it possible to run a single job for the creation of both the files.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not giving any details about your job configuration. Are you building with some plugin? Are you using command line?

Without more information, all I can say is: use 2 build steps to get 2 artifacts

*Edit after OP comment:*
Since you are using Xcode plugin, just set up 2 builds steps, one for IPA on for .xcarchive.

In your jobs **Configuration**, under **Build** section (where I assume you already have 1 instance of Xcode build configured), scroll down till you see **Add Build Step** button, click it and select **Xcode** build from there again.

Configure your second instance of Xcode build, and just change the whether it's IPA or not, and change the **Build output directory** to something that won't conflict with the first instance. Then modify your **Archive artifacts** post-build action to pick up both artifacts.

This will of course double the build time.